# Ibator didn't generate Oracle varchar2 field

Tags: oracle, javabeans, varchar2, auto-generate

I have table APP_REQ_APPROVE_COMPARE with following fields:

```
"ID"       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "TRACK_NO" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "REQ_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "OFFCODE"         CHAR(6 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "COMPARE_CASE_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "VEHICLE_NAME"    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "ENGINE_NO"       VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "BODY_NO"         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "HOLD_SHIP"       NUMBER,
    "OWNERSHIP"       VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    "RENT_NAME"       VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
    "CONTRACT"        VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "CONTRACT_NO"     VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
    "CONTRACT_DATE" DATE,
    "ISLAWBREAKERRENT" CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "MISTAKE_DETAIL"   VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    "COMPARE_REASON"   VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    "CREATE_BY"        NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CREATE_ON" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "UPDATE_BY" NUMBER,
    "UPDATE_ON" DATE,
```

When I generate a java bean using Ibator , I didn't find trackNo, VehicalName, ... (all fields defined as varchar2).

What is the problem in my case?  Here is my Ibator configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ibatorConfiguration
  PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Apache iBATIS Ibator Configuration 1.0//EN"
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/ibator-config_1_0.dtd">   
<ibatorConfiguration>
    <classPathEntry location="/dos/connector/oracle_jdbc.jar"/>
    <ibatorContext id="autoPerson" defaultModelType="flat" 
                                           targetRuntime="Ibatis2Java2">
        <jdbcConnection 
                    connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.42.144:1521:orcl"
            driverClass="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            userId="user"
            password="password"/>    
        <javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.ko.model"
                                targetProject="FormConfig">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
            <property name="trimStrings" value="true"/>
        </javaModelGenerator>
        <sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.ko.map" targetProject="FormConfig">
            <property name="enableSubPackages" value="true"/>
        </sqlMapGenerator>    
        <daoGenerator
            targetPackage="com.ko.model.dao"
            type="SPRING"
            targetProject="FormConfig"
            implementationPackage="com.ko.model.dao.impl" >
            <property name="enableSubPackges" value="true"/>
            <property name="methodNameCalculator" value="extended"/>
        </daoGenerator>    
        <table tableName="APP_REQ_APPROVE_COMPARE" 
                   domainObjectName="AppReqApproveCompare"/>
<ibatorConfiguration>
```

Comment: Please specify the problem more detailed. How to understand "there are no trackNo, VehicalName" ?

Comment: I got the answer from this thread http://www.mail-archive.com/user-java@ibatis.apache.org/msg15334.html

Answer (score 1):

Ibator Version 1.2.0, Bugs Fixed:
Fixed the JavaTypeResolver so that columns with unsupported data types may be overridden by configuration.